# Randomly place UIImageViews and then be able to find them

Tags: iphone, random, uiimageview, cgpoint

So I want to put some UIImageViews into my view.  I want them to be put in random places and I need to be able to get the location of each of the random UIImageView later in code.

I would just have 5 UIImageViews and do each one separately, but I may need more or less then 5 at a later point, So a standard, uniform way would be the best approach.

This is the code I'm working with right now:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {

    snack = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03-loopback.png"]];
    //snack.frame = CGRectMake(104, 76, 32, 22);
    snack.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random()%448, arc4random()%298, 32, 22);
    [self.view addSubview:snack];
    snackLocation = CGPointMake(snack.center.x, snack.center.y);
}
```

Comment: Does the location change? or does it stay static? is it the original location you want later in code?

Comment: I'm not sure yet.  For now, lets say it stays static and I want the origional location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use tags:

add in the for loop:

```
snack.tag=i;//Set the tag for each imageview
```

then to access to a subview you can loop on each subview of your main view

```
for (UIView *yourSubView in [self.view subviews]) {

        if (yourSubView.tag == YOUR_TAG) {
            //Do what you want with the view
                    break;//jump out the loop
        }
    }
```

You can also use this to write less code and access directlty to the frame of your subview:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:YOUR_TAG].frame=YOUR_FRAME;
```

Take a look the inspector in IB, each UI element has a property tag that you can set to identify your elements.

Comment: I'm using this code and in the for loop, I add each CGPoint to an array.  Then I go to retreve that value from the array later.  Is `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x,y)]` the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Store each UIImageView instance in a NSArray so you can get a hold of them later. Then just use the frame property again to retrieve the position:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {

    snack = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03-loopback.png"]];
    snack.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random()%448, arc4random()%298, 32, 22);
    [self.snackViews addObject:snack]; //self.snackViews is an NSMutableArray
    [self.view addSubview:snack];
}
```

Later on, you can get all the views from the `self.snackViews` array.